# Show menu items in a pop up window

Tags: java, android, menu

I've searched for it but nothing answered my question.

Right now I have something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kvsB.jpg)

But I need it to be like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr9vD.jpg)

I've read the documents in [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) but I'm not sure if it's the answer to my question or not it's just too complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try a dialog or alertdialog with a custom layout

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html